# CodeIgniter: form_input as readonly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following form input:

```
<?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'stockist['.$stockist->ID.'][ID]','value'=>form_decode($stockist->ID), 'class'=>'span1'));?>
```

I'd like to make this a read-only field, however any attempt to make this read=only using HTML syntax throws an error. Does anyone know if it's possible to make a form_input type read only?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'stockist['.$stockist->ID.'][ID]','value'=>form_decode($stockist->ID), 'class'=>'span1','readonly'=>'true'));?>
```

This will do your work! Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try as below :

```
$data_name = array(
'name' => 'emp_name',
'id' => 'emp_name_id',
'value' => 'John'
'readonly' => 'readonly'
);
echo form_input($data_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `'readonly' => 'readonly'` to make it read only

```
 <?php echo form_input(
        array('name' => "stockist['.$stockist->ID.'][ID]",
    'value' => form_decode($stockist->ID),
    'class' => 'span1', 
    'readonly' => 'readonly')); ?>
```

Read [CodeIgniter Form Helper](http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-form-helper/)